# Laravel - menu ativo

Tags: laravel

Estou a experimentar pela primeira vez desenvolver um website teste utilizando o Laravel e estou a seguir um video tutorial no youtube.
Está tudo a correr relativamente bem, mas estou com uma pequena questão que precisava da vossa ajuda.

Tenho um menu com 6 botões:

```
li class="principal {{ Request::is('pt/sport/homepage') ? "active" : "" }}"><a href="#">HOMEPAGE</a></li

li class="principal {{ Request::is('pt/sport/quem-somos') ? "active" : "" }}"><a href="#">QUEM SOMOS</a></li

li class="principal {{ Request::is('pt/sport/projetos', 'pt/sport/projetos/$projetoSlug') ? "active" : "" }}"><a href="#">PROJETOS</a></li

li class="principal {{ Request::is('pt/sport/produtos') ? "active" : "" }}"><a href="#">PRODUTOS</a></li

li class="principal {{ Request::is('pt/sport/metodologia') ? "active" : "" }}"><a href="#">METODOLOGIA</a></li

li class="principal {{ Request::is('pt/sport/contatos') ? "active" : "" }}"><a href="#">CONTATOS</a></li
```

O estado ativo está a funcionar na perfeição, mas nas páginas "Projetos" e "Produtos" vai existir uma grelha de fotos, que por sua vez ao clicar em uma das fotos, irá para uma página individual de apresentação do projecto ou produto. Até tudo ok.

A minha questão é a seguinte:
Quando carrego em Projectos, aparece a minha grelha de fotos e o botão mantém-se ativo, mas depois de clicar na foto para abrir o projeto individualmente (quem tem uma galeria de fotos) o botão projetos deixa de estar ativo.

Como mantenho o botão "Projetos" ativo?

Comment: Apenas como aparte, o `html` que colocou na pergunta ficou incompleto nas `tags`

Answer (score 0):

Para conseguir o efeito de active class eu uso o seguinte, é meio trabalhoso, mas como uso o NAV e depois uso o @extends('nav') e as demais @section.

```
<li class="{{ request()->is('/') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="{{asset('/')}}"><i class="icon-dashboard"></i><span>Página Inicial</span> </a> </li>
            <li class="{{ request()->is('atendimentos') ? 'active' : '' }} {{ request()->is('atendimentos/create') ? 'active' : '' }} {{ request()->is('atendimentos/*/edit') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="{{asset('atendimentos')}}"><i class="icon-list-alt"></i><span>Atendimentos</span> </a> </li>
            <li class="{{ request()->is('pessoas') ? 'active' : '' }} {{ request()->is('pessoas/create') ? 'active' : '' }} {{ request()->is('pessoas/*/edit') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="{{asset('pessoas')}}"><i class="icon-group"></i><span>Pessoas</span> </a></li>
            <li class="{{ request()->is('financeiro') ? 'active' : '' }} {{ request()->is('financeiro/create') ? 'active' : '' }} {{ request()->is('financeiro/*/edit') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="{{asset('financeiro')}}"><i class="icon-money"></i><span>Financeiro</span> </a></li>
```